# EF Migration: how I may use SqlFile() method?

Tags: entity-framework

I want to create an SP script for migration. I am trying to do it like this:

```
 public partial class _5 : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        SqlFile(@"D:\Scripts\Procedure");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {

    }
}
```

But when I try to 'Update-Database' I get the error 'cannot find file'. Does anyone know how I may use this method for migration?

Comment: Have you tried appending the file extension? (ex. @"D:\Scripts\Procedure.sql")

Comment: Yes. It's rather strange, but it's work for me if file in bin/debug.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this, it works in version 6.1.3. Perhaps it was a bug in an older version. I have looked at the source code of this method. If the path is rooted, it uses that path, else it combines it with the `CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`.